# How do you centre windows using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: gnome, 18.10, window-management

I found some people talking about Compiz Config but I'm still really confused. I want to use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to centre a window. I don't want them to be resized or anything. Just centred.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Gnome (I haven't used it and don't like there way of forcefully enforcing their views), but on KDE, you have the freedom, just open system-settings

Navigate to Window Management -> Window Rules -> Add New Rule

Write the description you want, then match the type of window you want to be centred (by Window Types). You can use the button Detect Window Type for choosing the types of windows to be matched (for this rule to apply).

Next, in Size & Position, do whatever you want.

In Arrangement & Access tab there is a shortcut setting, fill it.

Then hit Apply.

Now when you hit the shortcut, every window that is matched gets this new rule applied to it.

[image: Window Rules in System Settings]

[image: A New Rule Window]